# How to get Innertexts of multiple <a> tags?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

This is my sample page. I want to get all inner texts of a tags to one string. I wrote code for that but it doesn't work correctly

```xml
<body>
    <div id="infor">
        <div id="genres">
            <a href="#" >Animation</a>
            <a href="#" >Short</a>
            <a href="#" >Action</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to get inner text of the All  tag to one string, I used this code to do that, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
class Values
{
    private HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument _markup;

    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb(); //creating object of HtmlWeb
    form1 frm = new form1;

    _markup = web.Load("mypage.html"); // load page

    public string Genres
    {
        get
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection headers = _markup.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@id, 'infor')]/a"); // I filter all of <a> tags in <div id="infor">
            if (headers != null)
            {
                string genres = "";
                foreach (HtmlNode header in headers) // I'm not sure what happens here. 
                {
                    HtmlNode genre = header.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//a[contains(@href, '#')]"); //I think an error occurred in here... 
                    if (genre != null)
                    {
                        genres += genre.InnerText + ", ";
                    }
                }
                return genres;
            }
            return String.Empty;
        }
    }

    frm.text1.text=Genres;
}
```

text1 (return value) is:

```
Animation, Animation, Animation,
```

But I want output like this:

```
Animation, Short, Action,
```

Comment: is `header` not the node you actually want to get the `InnerText` on? The genre selecting code looks like it is just saying get the first sibling which is obviously the same every time... What are you trying to do with that bit of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little Linq and using Descendants will get you there easier, I think.

```
var genreNode = _markup.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(n => n.Id.Equals("genre")).FirstOrDefault();
if (genreNode != null)
{
    // this pulls all <a> nodes under the genre div and pops their inner text into an array
    // then joins that array using the ", " as separator.
    return string.Join(", ", genreNode.Descendants("a")
        .Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("href", string.Empty).Equals("#"))
        .Select(n => n.InnerText).ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is the `header.ParentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//a[contains(@href, '#')]")` statement.  It's taking you back up to the parent `div` element, and then finding the first `a` element that matches the criteria (which is always the same one).  You already have the `a` node, so you could just check it's attributes via its properties rather than doing another select.  However, it's silly to do a second select when you could just do a single select that narrows it down in the first place, such as:

```
HtmlNodeCollection headers = _markup.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@id, 'infor')]/a[contains(@href, '#')]");
if (headers != null)
    {
    string genres = "";
    foreach (HtmlNode header in headers) // i not sure what happens here. 
        {
        genres += header.InnerText + ", ";
        }
    return genres;
    }
```